# Set radio button checked by its Text from a stored Dataset's value for WinForms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda, dataset, radio-button

I've the following code for identifying which radio button should be marked as *checked* in a Windows Form, based on a stored value in a Dataset:

```
int rowNum = 0; //Row# is defined by system usage; value = 0 for example purposes
String storedValue = Convert.ToString(myDS.Tables["myTableName"].Rows[rowNum]["myColumn"]);

foreach (RadioButton button in this.myRBGroupBox.Controls) {
       if (button.Text == storedValue) {
         button.Checked = true;
       }
}
```

Is this a good approach to solve this? is it a lambda alternative for this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: That code uses always row at index 0. Is it correct?

Comment: Right now I'm using this snippet at the FormLoad Event; but you are right, the idea is to use it in any row, based on the system's use case. I'll do a change in the code for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's use a lambda to do the same thing without an explicit loop.

```
int rowNum = 0; 
string storedValue = Convert.ToString(myDS.Tables["myTableName"].Rows[rowNum]["myColumn"]);
RadioButton rb = myRBGroupBox.Controls
                             .OfType<RadioButton>()
                             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == storedValue));
if(rb != null) rb.Checked = true;
```

Is it better? Well, there are some improvements from your original code.
For example, the `OfType<RadioButton>` guarantees to get only radio buttons from the GroupBox's controls and `FirstOrDefault` stops the enumeration when the first radiobutton that match the condition is found.
But all these improvements can be done also in *'normal'* code

```
foreach (Control ctrl in myRBGroupBox.Controls)
{
    RadioButton rb = ctrl as RadioButton;
    if (rb != null && rb.Text == storedValue) {
        rb.Checked = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Personally I find this last one more readable.

Comment: This works like a charm: thanks a lot for the detailed reply and improvements. It all seems that I cannot vote as answered, as I don't enough reputation score, but I'm pretty grateful for your help :)

Comment: Btw (for learning purposes), why does the "break;" command is needed? I though it was only required in the "Select - Case" clauses.

Comment: break stops the loop immediately after you have found the radiobutton that you want to change without needlessly looping on the other buttons after that one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This topic is fully answered :)